# StrictMode class in Android

Tags: java, android, api

I am working on Network based project in android, so, to prevent force close on Android ICS because of `Can't do network operation on UI Thread` , I must use the part of code such below or try to start my network operation on other thread, but I don't want to change the base code, so I should use the code as below on Android ICS. :

```
static {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

How can I make unique apk file to run in all android version ( >= 1.6 ) ? `android.os.StrictMode` is accessible for higher version of android, so, i can not try to use the above part of code in my Android Activity. So, which solution is better :

1. Using Reflections to run this part of code on higher versions of API ([*`As oracle docs, reflective operations have slower performance than their non-reflective counterparts`*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html))
2. Change my android build target to Android 4.1.1 (API 16) and try to change the `android:minSdkVersion` on AndroidManifest.xml

Or if you know any better ones, please let me know.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Change your code and move stuff away from the UI thread. Networking on UI thread is even slower than reflection

Comment: Good idea, but it has more time to spend! I want to do this without changing Networking and UI thread conflicts. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BUILD.VERSION and reflection to get over this compability problem (tested).

```
    if (Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) >= 9) {
        try {
            // StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.LAX);
            Class<?> strictModeClass = Class.forName("android.os.StrictMode", true, Thread.currentThread()
                    .getContextClassLoader());
            Class<?> threadPolicyClass = Class.forName("android.os.StrictMode$ThreadPolicy", true, Thread.currentThread()
                    .getContextClassLoader());
            Field laxField = threadPolicyClass.getField("LAX");
            Method setThreadPolicyMethod = strictModeClass.getMethod("setThreadPolicy", threadPolicyClass);
            setThreadPolicyMethod.invoke(strictModeClass, laxField.get(null));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: But _StrictMode_ is not defined in android API 6! So, I should change my android target to Android 4.1.1 with minSdk 6 ?

Comment: StrictMode is available from API level 9. I think you should have a minSdk for 1.6 and targetSdkVersion is more for behavioral / appearance changes, so If you need it you can also set that.

Comment: I've defined my android target to Android 4.1.1 and change the minSdk to 6, so, i use your part of code in my Activity, so, the problem is : `Call requires API level 9 (current min is 6): android.os.StrictMode#setThreadPolicy` and the hint of eclipse is using `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` or `@TargetApi(9)`. what should i do ?

Comment: I've updated the answer to contain a reflection based solution.

Comment: You can safely suppress Lint errors. These are just warnings. So use @SuppressLint("NewApi")

Comment: @nandeesh: I've use this part of code, but it contains error on ICS 4.1.1! But in fact, I think your comment is acceptable. So, thanks :)